# Parsing in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have generated some data from a MySQL query that I want to do two things with. The data is an array of names and IDs.

First I want to use the name portion for a jQuery autocomplete, so that the name is what you can select in the field. 
Secondly, I want to fire on select in the autocomplete something that will place the ID of the selected item into a hidden field.

Here is my JQuery:

```
    $("#contact").autocomplete(
                source: function(request, response){
                                $.ajax({
                                         url: "ajax/grabdata.php?",
                                         type: "GET",
                                         data: request,
                                         success: function (data) {
                                             response($.map(data, function (el) {
                                                 return {
                                                     label: el.item.name,
                                                     value: el.item.id
                                                 };
                                             }));
                                         }
                                     });
                            },
                            width: 260,
                            matchContains: true,
                            selectFirst: false,
                            select: function(event, ui){
                                    $('#contact').val(ui.label);
                                    $('#id').val(ui.value);
                            }
                    });
```

Here is how I grabbed the data in PHP (grabdata.php):

```
      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT contacts.id, contacts.firstname, contacts.lastname FROMcontacts WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$q%' OR lastname LIKE '%$q%')";
      $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
      while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
      $kdata[] = array(
            "name" => $rs['firstname'].' '.$rs['lastname']."\n",
            "id" => $rs['ID']."\n",
      );
      $dataset[] = $kdata;
      }
```

I can get the data, but I am having trouble parsing it into what I want. The name should be selectable in the autocomplete field, and the ID should be filled in based on the name chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are not using the select method parameters as you should:

```
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#contact').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#id').val(ui.item.value);
    }
```

You are missing the ".item". Check the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Is the rest of my notation okay?

Comment: I cannot tell about PHP part, but the autocomplete seems ok.